# Rename .tmp files to .TIF

Tags: bash

I have a script to rename a list of files that have been modified today. I would like it to delay between when the list is generated and when the files are renamed to make sure that they have completely download. The download is controlled by an external process and most files are less than 1MB, so waiting a minute before processing should be sufficient.
If I replace the while loop in the program below with the following line it works but I'm afraid that it will rename a file that is in the middle of being downloaded.

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f | grep .tmp | cut -c 3-19 | while read i ; do
```

**Program**

```
read file_list <<< $(find . -mtime -1 -type f | grep .tmp | cut -c 3-19)
echo $file_list
read -r -p "Were the correct filenames selected (Y/N):" prompt
if [[ $prompt == "y" || $prompt == "Y" ]]
then
    sleep 1m;
    while $file_list ; do
            echo 'mv '$i'.tmp '$i'.TIF'
            mv $i.tmp $i.TIF
    done
    echo 'Renaming complete';
else
    echo 'No action taken';
    exit 0
fi
```

Note:
This program is only a temporary patch to clean up a mess left by another program (created by someone else) that is not operating properly.

Comment: Two questions: What's your operating system? Do you know the PID of the downloading process?

Comment: Another computer (Windows) saves the file to a network drive and is also supposed to rename them when it has finished downloading them. The web server has access to the files and is supposed to pick up the tif's for processing but it isn't because they were never renamed. The program should be fixed shortly but in the mean time I did not want to have to rename 100+ files every day until it is fixed.

Comment: Shoot. That's unfortunate -- if it's a completely different computer saving to a network filesystem, `fuser` won't work, since it checks for processes accessing the file from the same computer.

Comment: Maybe you should use something like `-mmin +5` on the `find` operation to require a certain amount of time to have passed since last write?

Comment: ...by the way, another approach that would make sense for a lot of people in related scenarios (different process but on the same computer) would be to use incron, http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about, to trigger as soon as a file is closed. Doesn't help in this case where it's a separate machine downloading; that kind of detail really needs to be part of the question up-front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a cut at that script with fewer bugs:

```
# read files into an array; this fixes support for files with spaces, wildcard
# characters, newlines, etc. in their names.
declare -a file_list=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file; do
  fuser -- "$file" >/dev/null && continue # skip files which are open
  file_list+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -mtime -1 -name '*.tmp' -type f -print0)

# use printf '%q' to format nonprintable characters readably.
printf '%q\n' "${file_list[@]}"
read -r -p "Were the correct filenames selected (Y/N):" prompt
if [[ $prompt == "y" || $prompt == "Y" ]]; then
    for file in "${file_list[@]}"; do
      mv -i -- "$file" "${file%.tmp}.tif"
    done
    echo 'Renaming complete';
else
    echo 'No action taken';
    exit 0
fi
```

See the `fuser` command, which checks for whether the file is open.

---

It's been mentioned that the download is actually happening on a completely different system. This means that both `fuser` and `inotify`-style approaches are unusable.

If you're confident that downloads will never take more than, say, 5 minutes, the `find` command can be changed as follows:

```
find . -mtime -1 -mmin +5 -name '*.tmp' -type f -print0
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the improvements. The filenames I'm working with are standardized so in my case it would not have been a problem.

Comment: @Aaron, ...see the line calling `fuser` to check for whether the file is open. That's a Linuxism, but unfortunately, there's not going to be any completely platform-independent way to do this.

Comment: @Aaron, ...btw, I appreciate the fix in terms of using the correct variable name, but the `--` was intentional and important (otherwise you'd have bugs when a filename started with a `-` character).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use

```
sleep 2m  # minutes (in GNU sleep only; POSIX sleep would need 120)
```

or

```
sleep 5   # seconds
```

...between the list retrieval and the rename operations.

Comment: I know how to use sleep my question is regarding how to get the while #list_file to operate over the list.

Comment: +1 to wbt11a for this answer.  If you don't want the script to hang around for a minute while 'sleeping', then I would suggest using an `at` command to schedule the files for deletion 1 minute later.

Comment: @mti2935, huh? How does this solve the problem at all? Again, the download is being done asynchronously BY AN EXTERNAL PROCESS over which the OP has no control. How does sleep help in any way whatsoever?

Comment: In his original post, he says, "I would like it to delay between when the list is generated and when the files are renamed".  That's where the sleep (suggested by wbt11a) comes in.

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense, though it's an unfortunate approach (one of the pitfalls of asking how to make a specific implementation work, vs how best to solve a problem)

Comment: I hope the edit wasn't too heavy-handed -- had been too long since my downvote, and it was locked in unless the post was changed. Hopefully it helps make the answer make more sense with the question as-edited.